# Customize the progress bar in nsis

Tags: edit, nsis, progress

I am new to NSIS scripting and I am trying to get around the scripting tool.

I created a sample installer, using MUI2.

I have used `MUI_INSTFILES_PROGRESSBAR smooth` Command. But that doesn't have any effect. Can any one help me out? Below snippet is the code I created.

```
!define MUI_INSTALLCOLORS "C0BCEB C0BCEB"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_PROGRESSBAR smooth
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom progressbar style and colors only work on <= Win2000 and maybe when Visual Styles are disabled on later systems. Google `PBS_SMOOTH` for more information...

Comment: Wasn't there some issues with "XPStyles on" directive? With this description it is just blind guess though.. :(

Comment: Yes XPStyle does play a part in this so you have to make a choice, the "correct" platform look or special progressbar. Maybe with XPStyle On you might still get the smooth style if themes are off system wide? (the service is stopped or user has chosen the classic theme).